# wsl2 fail to change file permissions

Tags: file-permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, chmod

I am working on wsl2 of win10:

```
PS C:\Users\Gaowei> wsl -l -v
  NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04    Running         2
```

After entering wsl, I make a file of test.md:

```
➜  ~ ls -l test.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gaowei gaowei 0 Aug 25 17:17 test.md
```

then try to change its permissions:

```
➜  ~ chmod 755 test.md
➜  ~ ls -l test.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gaowei gaowei 0 Aug 25 17:17 test.md
➜  ~ sudo chmod 755 test.md
➜  ~ ls -l test.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 gaowei gaowei 0 Aug 25 17:17 test.md
```

Unfortunately, it turn out to be stay unchanged.

My machine info:

```
gaowei@Spiritme
---------------
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64
Kernel: 4.19.104-microsoft-standard
Uptime: 4 mins
Packages: 1068 (dpkg)
Shell: zsh 5.8
Terminal: /dev/pts/0
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics (6) @ 2.370GHz
Memory: 75MiB / 12277MiB
```

what's the problem it might be?

Comment: Are you creating your file from Windows side? For example: `/mnt/c/Users/user`

Answer (score 13):

The problem was solved by creating `/etc/wsl.conf` file and configuring it as:

```
# Enable extra metadata options by default
[automount]
enabled = true
root = /mnt/
options = "metadata,umask=22,fmask=11"
mountFsTab = false
# Enable DNS – even though these are turned on by default, we'll specify here just to be explicit.
[network]
generateHosts = true
generateResolvConf = true
```

Reference : [wsl.conf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-per-distro-launch-settings-with-wslconf)

Comment: Can you explain a little why this configuration is supposed to fix the issue? thanks

Comment: The `options = "metadata"` section is what is needed. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50856772/1880761 for more detail.

Comment: You'll also need to wait 8 seconds or restart WSL in order for the changes to take effect.

Comment: not work for me